# NixOS and ghc-mod - Module not found

Tags: haskell, emacs, nixos

I'm experimenting a problem with the interaction between the ghc-mod plugin in emacs, and NixOS 14.04. Basically, once packages are installed via `nix-env -i`, they are visible from ghc and ghci, recognised by haskell-mode, but not found by ghc-mod.

To avoid information duplication, you can find all details, and the exact replication of the problem in a VM, in the bug ticket https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod/issues/269

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current, default, package management set up for Haskell on NixOS does work will with packages that use the ghc-api, or similar (`ghc-mod`, `hint`, plugins, hell, ...) run time resources. It takes a little more work to create a Nix expression that integrates them well into the rest of the environment. It is called making a wrapper expression for the package, for an example look at how GHC is installed an operates on NixOS.

It is reasonable that this is difficult since you are trying to make a install procedure that is atomic, but interacts with an unknown number of other system packages with their own atomic installs and updates. It is doable, but there is a quicker work around.

Look at this [example on the install page on the wiki](https://nixos.org/wiki/Haskell#Local_use_via_Nixpkgs_config). Instead of trying to create a `ghc-mod` package that works atomically you weld it on to ghc so ghc+ghc-mod is an atomic update.

I installed ghc+ghc-mod with the below install script added to my `~/.nixpkgs/nixpkgs.nix` file.

```
hsEnv = haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (self : [                            
  self.ghc                                                                   
  self.ghcMod                                                                
  # add more packages here                                                   
]);
```

Install package with something like:

```
nix-env -i hsEnv
```

or better most of the time:

```
nix-env -iA nixpkgs.haskellPackages.hsEnv
```

I have an alias for the above so I do not have to type it out every time. It is just:

```
nixh hsEnv
```

The down side of this method is that other Haskell packages installed with `nix-env -i[A]` will not work with the above installation. If I wanted to get everything working with the lens package then I would have to alter the install script to include `lens` like:

```
hsEnv = haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (self : [                            
  self.ghc                                                                   
  self.ghcMod 
  self.lens                                                               
  # add more packages here                                                   
]);
```

and re-install. Nix does not seem to use a different installation for `lens` or `ghc-mod` in hsEnv and with the ghc from `nix-env -i ghc` so apparently only a little more needs to happen behind the scenes most of the time to combine existing packages in the above fashion.

`ghc-mod` installed fine with the above script but I have not tested out its integration with Emacs as of yet.

### Additional notes added to the github thread

DanielG:

> I'm having a bit of trouble working with this environment, I can't even get cabal install to behave properly :/ I'm just getting lots of errors like:

With Nix and NixOS you pretty much never use Cabal to install at the global level

- Make sure to use sandboxes, if you are going to use `cabal-install`. You probably do not need it but its there and it works.
- Use `ghcWithPackages` when installing packages like `ghc-mod`, `hint`, or anything needs heavy runtime awareness of existing package (They are hard to make atomic and `ghcWithPackages` gets around this for GHC).
- If you are developing install the standard suite of posix tools with `nix-env -i stdenv`. NixOS does not force you to have your command line and PATH cultured with tools you do not necessarily need.
- cabal assumes the existence a few standard tools such as `ar`, `patch`(I think), and a few others as well if memory services me right.

If you use the standard install method and/or `ghcWithPackages` when needed then NixOS will dedup, on a package level (If you plot a dependency tree they will point to the same package in `/nix/store`, `nix-store --optimise` can always dedup the store at a file level.), many packages automatically unlike cabal sandboxes.

## Response to comment

```
[carlo@nixos:~]$ nix-env -iA nixos.pkgs.hsEnv

installing `haskell-env-ghc-7.6.3'
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/39dn9h2gnp1pyv2zwwcq3bvck2ydyg28-haskell-env-ghc-7.6.3.drv
building path(s) `/nix/store/minf4s4libap8i02yhci83b54fvi1l2r-haskell-env-ghc-7.6.3'
building /nix/store/minf4s4libap8i02yhci83b54fvi1l2r-haskell-env-ghc-7.6.3
collision between `/nix/store/1jp3vsjcl8ydiy92lzyjclwr943vh5lx-ghc-7.6.3/bin/haddock' and `/nix/store/2dfv2pd0i5kcbbc3hb0ywdbik925c8p9-haskell-haddock-ghc7.6.3-2.13.2/bin/haddock' at /nix/store/9z6d76pz8rr7gci2n3igh5dqi7ac5xqj-builder.pl line 72.
builder for `/nix/store/39dn9h2gnp1pyv2zwwcq3bvck2ydyg28-haskell-env-ghc-7.6.3.drv' failed with exit code 2
error: build of `/nix/store/39dn9h2gnp1pyv2zwwcq3bvck2ydyg28-haskell-env-ghc-7.6.3.drv' failed
```

It is the line that starts with collision that tells you what is going wrong:

```
collision between `/nix/store/1jp3vsjcl8ydiy92lzyjclwr943vh5lx-ghc-7.6.3/bin/haddock' and `/nix/store/2dfv2pd0i5kcbbc3hb0ywdbik925c8p9-haskell-haddock-ghc7.6.3-2.13.2/bin/haddock' at /nix/store/9z6d76pz8rr7gci2n3igh5dqi7ac5xqj-builder.pl line 72.
```

It is a conflict between two different haddocks. Switch to a new profile and try again. Since this is a welding together ghc+packages it should not be installed in a profile with other Haskell packages. That does not stop you from running binaries and interrupters from both packages at once, they just need to be in their own name space so when you call haddock, cabal, ghc, there is only one choice per profile.

If you are not familiar with profiles yet you can use:

```
nix-env -S /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/<user>/<New profile name>
```

The default profile is either `default` or `channels` do not which one it will be for your set up. But check for it so you can switch back to it later. There are some tricks so that you do not have to use the `/nix/var/nix/profiles/` directory to store you profiles to cut down on typing but that is the default location.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, when I try to do what is suggested in the wiki (both in the local and global config, but let's focus on the local), and do a ```nix-env -iA nixos.pkgs.hsEnv```, I get [this error](http://lpaste.net/105621) even when using the basic [configuration](http://lpaste.net/105622)

Comment: @meditans - It looks like you should install hsEnv in a new profile, at least from the error.  More detail in answer. I did not double check the config.nix expression as of yet.

Comment: Ok, I have another question. I didn't manage, in the end, to solve the problem in the previous comment with a change of profile. But I did a fresh installation, removing from my global configuration every file related to ghc (except xmonad in the graphic configuration, which, if I understood correctly, is itself atomic).
After installation, I did the wiki command, obtaining this [error](http://lpaste.net/105688) which is very similar to the previous one. May this also be a profile error?

Comment: @meditans - xmonad does depend on ghc since it is built from source.  I run xmoand on my system but it does not have to be in the same profile I am developing in. In my .xsession I switch to the profile that has xmonad set up everythign for X11 including xmonad, then switch back to the old profile.  Could you post 'nix-env -q "*"` on the profile in question that should list the installed packages locally. Your `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` may also have some globally installed packages, if it is not the default `configuration.nix`, so posting that as well would be a good idea.

Comment: In this new configuration (but also the previous), I have few, if any, installed package. In this specific one, ```nix-env -q "*"``` returns only ```dejavu-fonts-2.34```. For my global configuration files, you can refer to ```https://github.com/meditans/dotFiles```

Comment: You have quite a few haskell packages at the global level in you [`configurations.nix`](https://github.com/meditans/dotFiles/blob/master/configuration.nix#L23) including a ghc version.  `ghcWithPackages` method is trying to install a new version of ghc most of the time it will beable to uninstall the pervious version and install the new, occasionally their are conflicts that it can not resolve.  I would move those system packages to user profile there is a good chance that is the problem and is more idiomatic as well.

Comment: Update: I'm beginning to think that this isn't a profile problem. I did the following: imported the VB appliance into VBox (so, plain experience, without anything haskell-related modified by me), did a ```nix-channel --update nixos``` as root, and than copied the wiki snippet in .nixpkgs/config.nix and ```nix-env -iA nixos.pkgs.hsEnv```. It still complains with the same error of a few comments ago.

Comment: @meditans - That is good evidence that something else is going on. Try `self.ghc` rather then `self.haskellPlatform`. It could be something wrong with haskellPlatform expression. What does `nix-channel --list` give you? I can not reproduce the error on `https://nixos.org/channesl/nixpkgs-unstable` on a fresh profile.  Different users can have different channels.  So if you are updating your root you do not necessarily update your user profile.

Comment: I get the same error substituting ```self.ghc``` to ```self.haskellPlatform```. There wasn't a channel in user ```demo```, so I added it with ```nix-channel --add http://nixos.org/channels/nixos-14.04 nixos```. I'm getting the same [error](http://lpaste.net/105806), however

Comment: @meditans - That is a new/different error. The builder user tried to delete a file and failed due to permissions.  Not clear why the builder would not have permissions, those should be set when nixos is installed and it seems like it would cause numerous problems, not just problems with a individual package.  I would use the `--show-trace` option to see if you can find out more.  There is also verbose -v, -vv,...-vvvvv.

Comment: ok, the problem we were facing was a known ghcWithPackages bug. It can be solved with the exact code in the wiki you linked, but substituting ```ghcWithPackages``` with ```ghcWithPackagesOld```.
In this way, I didn't need to do anything with profiles. Thanks for your help throughout this thread!